# Erdős's proof of Sylvester's theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Sylvester's theorem states that the product of $k$ consecutive integers $>k$ has a prime factor $p>k$. Erdős gave a short proof for it, but I can't find Erdős's proof online. Can anyone give a sketch of the proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is available on-line [here](http://mathemathematics123.blogspot.com/2012/01/proof-by-paul-erdos-of-sylvesters.html) in white on black and [here](http://mathematicalspectacles.blogspot.com/2012/04/proof-by-paul-erdos-of-sylvesters.html) in black on white. And [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) is a PDF of Erdős’s paper, *A Theorem of Sylvester and Schur*.

**Added:** As Coffee_Table notes in the comments, Paul Erdős’s papers from $1929$ through $1989$ are available [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html); the site’s [front page](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/) has a search engine.

Comment: as a side note, if you'd like any proof ever done by Paul Erdos see [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html).

Comment: @Coffee_Table Thanks!

Comment: @fan: You’re welcome!

Comment: This is an old answer--about 5 years old--but I'd like to point out that the first link doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: first and second link not working. those blogs are gone. should someone post a summary of the proof here ? just to make it self-sufficient.